# Java Scanner & User Input text box

Tags: java, multiplication, bluej

I have been having a little trouble with my java code in BlueJ IDE. What i'm trying to do is ask the user: "what is 1 x 3?" and have a text box where the user enters their answer, and presses a button to submit it. If their answer is correct, the program will display a message saying "correct" and "incorrect, please try again" if the answer is wrong. This is the code that I made:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //prompt the user to enter thier answer to the question
//create two labels to explain input 

double answer = 3; //the correct answer to the multiplication question

   JLabel labelAnswer =  new JLabel("What is 1 x 3?"); //ask user this
   double userAnswer = input.nextDouble();
   //prompt the user to enter the gallons
   if (userAnswer = 3) //if the user enters 3 into the text box, a message will be displayed saying: Correct!{
     { if (userAnswer == 3) 
      {System.out.println("Correct!");  

      break;
    }
    if (userAnswer != 3) //if the user enters anything others than 3, it is incorrect
    {
        System.out.println("Incorrect, Please try again!"); 

    }
```

The error code that I get says that the double cannot be converted to boolean. 
How would I fix this issue?
Thanks

Comment: Do you know the difference between `=` and `==`?

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing Swing GUI and console code. Either use a GUI and get the input in the GUI or scrap the GUI and use a `Scanner(System.in)`, but again, don't use both or else you're in for some unpleasantness.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix this:

```
if(userAnswer = 3)
```

Change it to:

```
if(userAnswer == 3)
```

Also can I recommend this to save space?

```
if(userAnswer == 3)
    System.out.println("Correct!");
else
    System.out.println("Incorrect, Please try again!");
```

Instead of:

```
if (userAnswer = 3) //if the user enters 3 into the text box, a message will be displayed saying: Correct!{
     { if (userAnswer == 3) 
      {System.out.println("Correct!");  

      break;
    }
    if (userAnswer != 3) //if the user enters anything others than 3, it is incorrect
    {
        System.out.println("Incorrect, Please try again!"); 

    }
```

Also, you call `break`, but you never enter  a loop that you can break out of.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, like what imbibes said, = and == is different. If you use =, you are actually assigning a value, while when you use ==, you are actually comparing two different values.

Also, you should not use break unless you're using a switch statement. I think you mistaken it by

```
 return
```

if ever.

Comment: You can, and should use breaks in loops as well.

Comment: wouldn't this defeat the purpose of the condition of a loop?

Comment: Breaks are appropriate in loops, but not always needed. That is what I meant to say. Like if I had an array and I was searching for an item inside the array, I would keep searching, until I found it, and then I can call break. Otherwise the loop would keep going until the condition is met even though I have fulfilled my task.